# How to sort 3D array of chars in C by qsort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, qsort, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble with sorting a 3D array of char with `qsort()` in C.
I want to sort the array by length of the string.

I found this code for sorting a 2D array:

```
int compare(const void *name1, const void *name2)
{
    const char *name1_ = *(const char **)name1;
    const char *name2_ = *(const char **)name2;

    return strcmp(name1_, name2_);
}
```

And I modified the code to this:

```
int compare(const void *name1, const void *name2)
{    

    const char *name1_ = *(const char ***)name1;
    const char *name2_ = *(const char ***)name2;

    if(strlen(name1_)>strlen(name2_))
    {
      return 1;
    }

    if(strlen(name1_)<strlen(name2_))
    {
      return -1;
    }
    else
    {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work, and I have no idea how to do it.

For example. I want to sort array like this:

```
char * array1 [][2] = {
     { "murderer", "termination specialist" },
     { "failure", "non-traditional success" },
     { "specialist", "person with certified level of knowledge" },
     { "incorrect answer", "alternative answer" }
    };
```

To this format:

```
char * array1 [][2] = {
         { "incorrect answer", "alternative answer" }, 
         { "specialist", "person with certified level of knowledge" },
         { "murderer", "termination specialist" },
         { "failure", "non-traditional success" }
        };
```

Comment: What doesn't work?  Compilation error... logic error...

Comment: Show how your array is defined, and explain exactly what you mean by sorting a 3D array.  Sorting only makes sense in one dimension.  With more than one dimension, you need additional criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the sorting rules you would like to introduce, I can see C pointer issue in your implementation. If code used successfully for the 2D case:

```
const char name1_ = *(const char **)name1;
```

My guess is that casting for 3D case is not correct:

```
const char name1_ = *(const char ***)name1;
```

because this should be

```
const char name1_ = **(const char ***)name1;
```

since in 3D case you need to dereference pointer twice.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char *Row[2];

int compare(const void *row1, const void *row2){
    const Row *name1 = (const Row*)row1;
    const Row *name2 = (const Row*)row2;
    return strlen((*name2)[0]) - strlen((*name1)[0]);
}
/* or
int compare(const void *row1, const void *row2){
    const char *name1 = *(const char**)row1;
    const char *name2 = *(const char**)row2;
    return strlen(name2) - strlen(name1);
}
*/

int main(){
    char * array1 [][2] = {
        { "murderer", "termination specialist" },
        { "failure", "non-traditional success" },
        { "specialist", "person with certified level of knowledge" },
        { "incorrect answer", "alternative answer" }
    };
    qsort(array1, sizeof(array1)/sizeof(*array1), sizeof(*array1), compare);
    {//check 
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<4;++i)
            printf("\"%s\", \"%s\"\n", array1[i][0], array1[i][1]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: -1 because it's not an answer - it just a copy paste of some code  example (relevant, but anyway, there should be at least minimal explanation)

Comment: @pmod It's enough just to present the code that actually works.

Comment: This code shows clearly that pointer to `char *Row[2]` what qsort passes to compare that it is.

Comment: "It's enough just to present the code that actually works." Sorry,but this is what I can't agree on. This encourages SO misuse - people post here broken code and take away fixed. This is not an idea behind SO. People should learn how to program and use tools ...

Comment: @pmod It is a difference of opinion. Code actually shown is a representation most obvious.